# how to add this library to my project?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0, nrf51, dfu

link I want add the [dfu library](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-DFU-Library) to my project.
it has a download oètopn, but there is no direct download and it says to use Gradle to add it.
Anyway, the [documentation](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-DFU-Library/tree/release/documentation) says to do this step.

> Clone the project, or just the DFULibrary folder (using sparse-checkout) to a temporary location.
>
> Copy the DFULibrary folder to your projects root, for example to AndroidstudioProjects.
>
> Add the dfu module to your project:
>
> Add '..:DFULibrary:dfu' to the settings.gradle file: include ':app', '..:DFULibrary:dfu'
>
> Open Project Structure -> Modules -> app -> Dependencies tab and add dfu module dependency. You may also edit the build.gradle file in your app module manually by adding the following dependency: compile project(':..:DFULibrary:dfu')

But I can't find the DFULibrary folder in this project .

Comment: Please show your app gradle file

Comment: You say "but i cant find DFULibrary folder in this project". The instructions say "Clone the project" [...] "Copy the DFULibrary folder to your projects root". Have you copied the DFULibrary folder into your project?

Answer (score 3):

Add in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'no.nordicsemi.android:dfu:1.0.4'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I started using it today. It is a bit different.

Use menu File -> Project Structure -> Modules.

[image]

Click to choose library dependency 
[image]

Search the library that you want to add in your project and click on to import.
[image]

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
}
```

Hope this will help you enough.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://gradleplease.appspot.com/ and search for the library you want.

Go to build.gradle file and add it under dependencies{...} module and add that line and hit the sync button

```
dependencies {
    compile 'no.nordicsemi.android:dfu:0.6'
}
```